# Angular service is called twice when have multiple components

Tags: angular

I have an angular page with includes the same component twice. A small presentation and a popup.

Both components should use the same dataset as retrieved from the server. But how to avoid that the service is called twice?  The server can handle this, but it is a waste of bandwidth. Not nice for mobile users.

Of course, I can load the data on the parent component, but I think this is not the way forward. The parent component should not have any knowledge of the child data.

Comment: Why don't you store it in the service, so it doesn't fetch it the second time a component asks for it?

Comment: I tried this. The second call is fired before the first call has an answer from the server. So the store is still empty.

Comment: So return an observable or promise that you can provide the value through when available.

Comment: Who is making the http request ? the parent by a `service`, can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

As rightly suggested by @jonrsharpe in the comments section of the question, you can store the response in the injectable service and return the response as an observable in subsequent calls. In order to implement this, you can modify the injectable service in the following way,

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };

  responseBody: any;


  postResponse(requestObject: any ) {
    return this.http.post(API_URL, requestObject, this.httpOptions); // Method gets invoked initially
  }

  storeResponse(response: any) {
    this.responseBody = response; // Method gets invoked after the initial call has received the response object
  }

  getResponse():Observable<any[]> {
    return of(this.responseBody); // Method gets invoked by subsequent calls
  }

}
```

Comment: Missing some pieces here for how to call each method and when...

Comment: The rest call will still be sent twice as long as one of the calls hasn't completed, and the variable's still empty. The only way I can imagine is by using ngxs, but then you'll still have to call `this.store.dispatch()` from the parent component anyway. Unless you'd add a `pending` variable to the state.

Answer (score 0):

See if this pseudocode works for you:

```
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  public data$ = this.http.get("api").pipe(
    shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: boolean})
  )
}
```

`bufferSize` obviously sets the buffer size to 1, so only the latest value is replayed, and `refCount` will cause the request to be executed again after all the subscribers have unsubscribed and something is subscribing again (if you want it to be cached indefinitely, just use `shareReplay(1)`)